# does setInterval differ from phone device to another?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, timer, setinterval

does setInterval differ from phone device to another ?
I'm trying to build HTML5 game to run on many different mobile phone device.
I'm using setInterval for animation and timer, noticed that speed of the game on Galaxy SII is higher than the speed on HTC Nexuse One !!!
HTC take more than 30 seconds for finish a 20 second timer !!!!
Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

The only idea is to test the minimum `setInterval` allowed by a browser on the mobile devices.

```
var date = Date.now();
setInterval(function(){
    var d = Date.now() - window.date;
    console.log(d);
}, 0 );
```

Every browser has a different value; Also you could try and test for `requestAnimationFrame` and sniff if it is implemented if not you can find out easily the code for it an use it this way, even if it uses `setInterval` also, but it takes in consideration the frame rate and the minimum time allowed by each browser.

Comment: true. requestAnimationFrame is the only reliable way of being in sync with the device display. Beware though that you should still put an upper frequency limit to your game loop for 100Hz/120Hz/... displays (i have a 120Hz laptop and games which uses requestAnimationFrame make my computer overheat). So just do : if (lastRunTime-Date.now()<14) return; or like.

Comment: What about calling the funvtion using window.setTimeout(callTheFunction, 30) ?? is it stable or it will NOT work as required also ?

Comment: @Solieman It also depends on the timeout load. If you have 100 functions on the stack waiting to be timed out it could not run after exactly 30 ms. I would propose using requestAnimationFrame if exists or an equivalent code like here: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/